# JVM error with multipe MDB operations: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, ms-access, crash, jvm

I have an application processing some data and periodically writing that data into MDB files on disk. The application runs ok if i disable the MDB operations but fails after about 15minutes of operation with the following error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007f80b381069, pid=9288, tid=5216
#
# JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x1069]  RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x9
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\victor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\project\hs_err_pid9288.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Java Result: 1
```

I monitored the process memory and this is what i got: 
http://i62.tinypic.com/2nq6y6v.jpg

I only have one thread handling the I/O MDB operations. Any ideas what should I tweak to have it running normal?

More from error report file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007f80b381069, pid=9288, tid=5216
#
# JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x1069]  RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x9
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000d82b800):  JavaThread "Thread-32" [_thread_in_native, id=5216, stack(0x0000000010e50000,0x0000000010f50000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x0000000000000010

Registers:
RAX=0x000007f60bda4000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000008, RDX=0x0000000010f4ee30
RSP=0x0000000010f4ed38, RBP=0x0000000010f4eed0, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x000000000f81e1f0
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000007, R10=0x0000000000000007, R11=0x000000000be44c60
R12=0x0000000010f4ee30, R13=0x000000009e01ce90, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x000000000d82b800
RIP=0x000007f80b381069, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010297

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000010f4ed38)
0x0000000010f4ed38:   000007fff3d535b1 000000000000000c
0x0000000010f4ed48:   0000000000000001 0000000000000001
0x0000000010f4ed58:   0000000057dc8b57 000000000d82b800
0x0000000010f4ee08:   000000000d82b9d8 ffffffffffffffff
0x0000000010f4ee18:   0000000000000000 000000000000004b
0x0000000010f4ee28:   00000000028223a8 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000007f80b381069)
0x000007f80b381049:   c4 20 5b c3 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90
0x000007f80b381059:   90 90 90 90 90 90 90 65 48 8b 04 25 30 00 00 00
0x000007f80b381069:   f0 0f ba 71 08 00 48 8b 40 48 0f 83 ae 48 00 00
0x000007f80b381079:   48 89 41 10 c7 41 0c 01 00 00 00 33 c0 c3 90 90 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000007f60bda4000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000008 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000010f4ee30 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000d82b800
RSP=0x0000000010f4ed38 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000d82b800
RBP=0x0000000010f4eed0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000d82b800
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000000f81e1f0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000007 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000007 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000000be44c60 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000010f4ee30 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000d82b800
R13=0x000000009e01ce90 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000000d82b800 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000010e50000,0x0000000010f50000],  sp=0x0000000010f4ed38,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x1069]  RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x9

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.allocConnect(J[B)J+0
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLAllocConnect(J)J+30
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.allocConnection(J)J+6
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;I)V+37
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+129
j  java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+155
j  java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+41
J  scada.HMI.Alarms$UpdatePageThread.OperateUpdateMDBFile()V
j  scada.HMI.Alarms$UpdatePageThread.runUpdate()V+5
j  scada.HMI.Alarms$UpdatePageThread.run()V+35
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000bdd9000 JavaThread "Thread-492" [_thread_in_native, id=5612, stack(0x0000000016690000,0x0000000016790000)]
  0x000000000bddc000 JavaThread "Thread-491" [_thread_in_native, id=9164, stack(0x0000000016390000,0x0000000016490000)]
  0x000000000bdd7800 JavaThread "Thread-490" [_thread_in_native, id=9172, stack(0x0000000016290000,0x0000000016390000)]
  0x000000000e500800 JavaThread "Thread-489" [_thread_in_native, id=3560, stack(0x0000000016590000,0x0000000016690000)]
  0x000000000e4ff000 JavaThread "Thread-488" [_thread_in_native, id=6044, stack(0x000000000f410000,0x000000000f510000)]
  0x000000000bddb000 JavaThread "Thread-487" [_thread_in_native, id=3592, stack(0x000000000ce20000,0x000000000cf20000)]
  0x000000000bdd6000 JavaThread "Thread-486" [_thread_in_native, id=9240, stack(0x000000000cc20000,0x000000000cd20000)]
  0x000000000bdd9800 JavaThread "Thread-485" [_thread_in_native, id=9588, stack(0x000000000cb20000,0x000000000cc20000)]
  0x000000000bdda800 JavaThread "Thread-484" [_thread_in_native, id=3948, stack(0x000000000cd20000,0x000000000ce20000)]
  0x000000000e4fe800 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3388, stack(0x0000000016190000,0x0000000016290000)]
  0x000000000e4fd800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=9452, stack(0x0000000002610000,0x0000000002710000)]
  0x000000000e4fc000 JavaThread "Thread-41" [_thread_blocked, id=7756, stack(0x0000000016090000,0x0000000016190000)]
  0x000000000e503000 JavaThread "Thread-40" [_thread_blocked, id=9592, stack(0x0000000015f90000,0x0000000016090000)]
  0x000000000e4fd000 JavaThread "Thread-39" [_thread_in_Java, id=1216, stack(0x0000000015e90000,0x0000000015f90000)]
  0x000000000e501800 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=10108, stack(0x0000000015d90000,0x0000000015e90000)]
  0x000000000e502000 JavaThread "Thread-38" [_thread_blocked, id=2156, stack(0x0000000015c90000,0x0000000015d90000)]
  0x000000000e500000 JavaThread "Thread-37" [_thread_blocked, id=6084, stack(0x0000000015940000,0x0000000015a40000)]
  0x000000000d82b000 JavaThread "Thread-36" [_thread_blocked, id=7172, stack(0x0000000015840000,0x0000000015940000)]
  0x000000000d82d000 JavaThread "Thread-35" [_thread_blocked, id=5760, stack(0x0000000015740000,0x0000000015840000)]
  0x000000000d82c800 JavaThread "Thread-34" [_thread_blocked, id=9676, stack(0x0000000011630000,0x0000000011730000)]
  0x000000000d829800 JavaThread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1944, stack(0x0000000011050000,0x0000000011150000)]
  0x000000000d828800 JavaThread "Thread-33" [_thread_blocked, id=8264, stack(0x0000000010f50000,0x0000000011050000)]
=>0x000000000d82b800 JavaThread "Thread-32" [_thread_in_native, id=5216, stack(0x0000000010e50000,0x0000000010f50000)]
  0x000000000d82e800 JavaThread "Thread-31" [_thread_blocked, id=6776, stack(0x0000000010d50000,0x0000000010e50000)]
  0x000000000d82e000 JavaThread "Thread-30" [_thread_blocked, id=5724, stack(0x0000000010c50000,0x0000000010d50000)]
  0x000000000d82f800 JavaThread "Thread-29" [_thread_blocked, id=9904, stack(0x0000000010b50000,0x0000000010c50000)]
  0x000000000d82a000 JavaThread "Thread-28" [_thread_blocked, id=8800, stack(0x0000000010a50000,0x0000000010b50000)]
  0x000000000d9b0800 JavaThread "Thread-27" [_thread_blocked, id=8916, stack(0x0000000010950000,0x0000000010a50000)]
  0x000000000d9af000 JavaThread "Thread-26" [_thread_blocked, id=8796, stack(0x0000000010850000,0x0000000010950000)]
  0x000000000d9af800 JavaThread "Thread-25" [_thread_blocked, id=9604, stack(0x0000000010750000,0x0000000010850000)]
  0x000000000d9ac800 JavaThread "Thread-24" [_thread_blocked, id=7896, stack(0x0000000010650000,0x0000000010750000)]
  0x000000000d9ac000 JavaThread "Thread-23" [_thread_blocked, id=3548, stack(0x0000000010550000,0x0000000010650000)]
  0x000000000d9b2000 JavaThread "Thread-22" [_thread_blocked, id=6344, stack(0x0000000010450000,0x0000000010550000)]
  0x000000000d9b1000 JavaThread "Thread-21" [_thread_blocked, id=9444, stack(0x0000000010350000,0x0000000010450000)]
  0x000000000d9ad800 JavaThread "Thread-20" [_thread_blocked, id=508, stack(0x0000000010250000,0x0000000010350000)]
  0x000000000d9b2800 JavaThread "Thread-19" [_thread_blocked, id=4632, stack(0x0000000010110000,0x0000000010210000)]
  0x000000000d9ae000 JavaThread "Thread-18" [_thread_blocked, id=7616, stack(0x0000000010010000,0x0000000010110000)]
  0x000000000d548000 JavaThread "Thread-17" [_thread_blocked, id=6060, stack(0x000000000ff10000,0x0000000010010000)]
  0x000000000d547800 JavaThread "Thread-16" [_thread_blocked, id=6968, stack(0x000000000fe10000,0x000000000ff10000)]
  0x000000000d546800 JavaThread "Thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=10180, stack(0x000000000fd10000,0x000000000fe10000)]
  0x000000000d546000 JavaThread "Thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=4652, stack(0x000000000fc10000,0x000000000fd10000)]
  0x000000000d545000 JavaThread "Thread-13" [_thread_blocked, id=5404, stack(0x000000000fb10000,0x000000000fc10000)]
  0x000000000d544800 JavaThread "Thread-12" [_thread_blocked, id=4404, stack(0x000000000fa10000,0x000000000fb10000)]
  0x000000000d543800 JavaThread "Thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=3384, stack(0x000000000f910000,0x000000000fa10000)]
  0x000000000d549000 JavaThread "Thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=7688, stack(0x000000000f710000,0x000000000f810000)]
  0x000000000d543000 JavaThread "Thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=8552, stack(0x000000000f610000,0x000000000f710000)]
  0x000000000d549800 JavaThread "Thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=9640, stack(0x000000000f510000,0x000000000f610000)]
  0x000000000d50b800 JavaThread "Thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=1400, stack(0x000000000f300000,0x000000000f400000)]
  0x000000000d50b000 JavaThread "Thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=9384, stack(0x000000000f200000,0x000000000f300000)]
  0x000000000d7e2800 JavaThread "Thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=9760, stack(0x000000000f100000,0x000000000f200000)]
  0x000000000bda1000 JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=9692, stack(0x000000000def0000,0x000000000dff0000)]
  0x000000000bda0800 JavaThread "Thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=7984, stack(0x000000000ddf0000,0x000000000def0000)]
  0x000000000bd15000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=8480, stack(0x000000000d370000,0x000000000d470000)]
  0x000000000bbfc000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5868, stack(0x000000000c6a0000,0x000000000c7a0000)]
  0x000000000bbfb000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=9704, stack(0x000000000c5a0000,0x000000000c6a0000)]
  0x000000000bbf8800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8804, stack(0x000000000c4a0000,0x000000000c5a0000)]
  0x000000000a144800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3584, stack(0x000000000b8e0000,0x000000000b9e0000)]
  0x000000000a13d800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9956, stack(0x000000000b7e0000,0x000000000b8e0000)]
  0x000000000a130800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7864, stack(0x000000000b6e0000,0x000000000b7e0000)]
  0x000000000a12f000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9008, stack(0x000000000b5e0000,0x000000000b6e0000)]
  0x000000000a12c000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8628, stack(0x000000000b4e0000,0x000000000b5e0000)]
  0x000000000a0c6000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8604, stack(0x000000000b3e0000,0x000000000b4e0000)]
  0x000000000a0bd000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9436, stack(0x000000000b2e0000,0x000000000b3e0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000a0b5800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000000b1e0000,0x000000000b2e0000] [id=9224]
  0x000000000a15d800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000000b9e0000,0x000000000bae0000] [id=3972]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 14272K, used 5122K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e19d0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 13760K, 33% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e0f30870,0x00000000e1820000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x00000000e1950000,0x00000000e19d0000,0x00000000e19d0000)
  to   space 768K, 0% used [0x00000000e1850000,0x00000000e1850000,0x00000000e1910000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97343K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7f0fea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000058d0000,0x0000000005bf0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000053e9000

Polling page: 0x0000000002550000

Code Cache  [0x0000000002810000, 0x0000000002ca0000, 0x0000000005810000)
 total_blobs=1511 nmethods=905 adapters=556 free_code_cache=46185Kb largest_free_block=45601600

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 738.239 Thread 0x000000000a13d800  953  s!         javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument::writeLock (86 bytes)
Event: 738.243 Thread 0x000000000a13d800 nmethod 953 0x0000000002c711d0 code [0x0000000002c71320, 0x0000000002c71788]
Event: 739.923 Thread 0x000000000a130800  954             org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot::configureDomainAxes (40 bytes)
Event: 739.926 Thread 0x000000000a13d800  955             org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot::configureRangeAxes (40 bytes)
Event: 739.927 Thread 0x000000000a130800 nmethod 954 0x0000000002a5a850 code [0x0000000002a5a9c0, 0x0000000002a5ab98]
Event: 739.929 Thread 0x000000000a13d800 nmethod 955 0x0000000002a5a310 code [0x0000000002a5a460, 0x0000000002a5a5e8]
Event: 743.933 Thread 0x000000000a130800  956             java.text.DecimalFormat::expandAffix (188 bytes)
Event: 743.939 Thread 0x000000000a130800 nmethod 956 0x0000000002a5bb10 code [0x0000000002a5bca0, 0x0000000002a5c1e0]
Event: 769.142 Thread 0x000000000a13d800  957  s!         scada.HMI.Alarms$UpdatePageThread::OperateUpdateMDBFile (597 bytes)
Event: 769.223 Thread 0x000000000a13d800 nmethod 957 0x0000000002c32990 code [0x0000000002c33060, 0x0000000002c36c00]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 803.981 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=432 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 15360K, used 15328K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e1a90000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 14720K, 100% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e1910000,0x00000000e1910000)
  from space 640K, 95% used [0x00000000e1960000,0x00000000e19f8000,0x00000000e1a00000)
  to   space 576K, 0% used [0x00000000e1a00000,0x00000000e1a00000,0x00000000e1a90000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97087K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7ecfea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
Event: 803.983 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=432 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 15104K, used 576K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e1a90000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 14528K, 0% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e18e0000)
  from space 576K, 100% used [0x00000000e1a00000,0x00000000e1a90000,0x00000000e1a90000)
  to   space 768K, 0% used [0x00000000e1910000,0x00000000e1910000,0x00000000e19d0000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97119K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7ed7ea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
}
Event: 805.224 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=433 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 15104K, used 15104K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e1a90000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 14528K, 100% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e18e0000,0x00000000e18e0000)
  from space 576K, 100% used [0x00000000e1a00000,0x00000000e1a90000,0x00000000e1a90000)
  to   space 768K, 0% used [0x00000000e1910000,0x00000000e1910000,0x00000000e19d0000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97119K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7ed7ea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
Event: 805.228 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=433 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 14976K, used 608K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e1a30000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 14336K, 0% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e18b0000)
  from space 640K, 95% used [0x00000000e1910000,0x00000000e19a8000,0x00000000e19b0000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000e19b0000,0x00000000e19b0000,0x00000000e1a30000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97199K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7eebea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
}
Event: 806.550 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=434 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 14976K, used 14944K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e1a30000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 14336K, 100% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e18b0000,0x00000000e18b0000)
  from space 640K, 95% used [0x00000000e1910000,0x00000000e19a8000,0x00000000e19b0000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000e19b0000,0x00000000e19b0000,0x00000000e1a30000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97199K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7eebea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
Event: 806.552 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=434 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 14656K, used 512K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e1a30000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 14144K, 0% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e1880000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x00000000e19b0000,0x00000000e1a30000,0x00000000e1a30000)
  to   space 768K, 0% used [0x00000000e18b0000,0x00000000e18b0000,0x00000000e1970000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97255K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7ef9ea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
}
Event: 807.853 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=435 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 14656K, used 14656K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e1a30000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 14144K, 100% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e1880000,0x00000000e1880000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x00000000e19b0000,0x00000000e1a30000,0x00000000e1a30000)
  to   space 768K, 0% used [0x00000000e18b0000,0x00000000e18b0000,0x00000000e1970000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97255K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7ef9ea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
Event: 807.855 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=435 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 14592K, used 640K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e19d0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 13952K, 0% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e1850000)
  from space 640K, 100% used [0x00000000e18b0000,0x00000000e1950000,0x00000000e1950000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000e1950000,0x00000000e1950000,0x00000000e19d0000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97271K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7efdea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
}
Event: 809.068 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=436 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 14592K, used 14592K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e19d0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 13952K, 100% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e1850000,0x00000000e1850000)
  from space 640K, 100% used [0x00000000e18b0000,0x00000000e1950000,0x00000000e1950000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000e1950000,0x00000000e1950000,0x00000000e19d0000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97271K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7efdea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
Event: 809.070 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=436 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 14272K, used 512K [0x00000000e0ab0000, 0x00000000e19d0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 13760K, 0% used [0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e0ab0000,0x00000000e1820000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x00000000e1950000,0x00000000e19d0000,0x00000000e19d0000)
  to   space 768K, 0% used [0x00000000e1850000,0x00000000e1850000,0x00000000e1910000)
 ParOldGen       total 128192K, used 97343K [0x00000000a2000000, 0x00000000a9d30000, 0x00000000e0ab0000)
  object space 128192K, 75% used [0x00000000a2000000,0x00000000a7f0fea0,0x00000000a9d30000)
 PSPermGen       total 37248K, used 22148K [0x000000009ce00000, 0x000000009f260000, 0x00000000a2000000)
  object space 37248K, 59% used [0x000000009ce00000,0x000000009e3a1388,0x000000009f260000)
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 554.179 Thread 0x000000000d82b000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x0000000002b98c90
Event: 555.560 Thread 0x000000000e501800 Uncommon trap -58 fr.pc 0x000000000295ec8c
Event: 562.898 Thread 0x000000000bd15000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x00000000029ed038
Event: 563.638 Thread 0x000000000d82a000 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0x0000000002c6a354
Event: 563.700 Thread 0x000000000d828800 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x0000000002a05c78
Event: 564.063 Thread 0x000000000bd15000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x0000000002a5e990
Event: 564.063 Thread 0x000000000bd15000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x0000000002a54834
Event: 564.075 Thread 0x000000000bd15000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002a384e8
Event: 568.653 Thread 0x000000000bd15000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002a384e8
Event: 623.744 Thread 0x000000000d82a000 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0x0000000002c4a24c

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 798.178 Thread 0x000000000da2f000 Threw 0x00000000e155c278 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 799.376 Thread 0x000000000da2d800 Threw 0x00000000e143c588 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 800.571 Thread 0x000000000da28000 Threw 0x00000000e129eca0 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 801.789 Thread 0x000000000da2b000 Threw 0x00000000e108a318 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 802.985 Thread 0x000000000da2c000 Threw 0x00000000e0f246e8 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 804.175 Thread 0x000000000bdd7800 Threw 0x00000000e0ce0ca8 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 805.377 Thread 0x000000000bddc800 Threw 0x00000000e0bf2148 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 806.587 Thread 0x000000000bdd8000 Threw 0x00000000e0b05d08 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 807.782 Thread 0x000000000bdd9000 Threw 0x00000000e17951b8 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 808.988 Thread 0x000000000bdd6800 Threw 0x00000000e16c1600 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u17\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742

Events (10 events):
Event: 807.782 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 807.782 Thread 0x000000000bdd9000 Thread exited: 0x000000000bdd9000
Event: 807.853 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 807.855 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 808.834 Thread 0x000000000bdd9000 Thread added: 0x000000000bdd9000
Event: 808.988 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 808.988 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 808.988 Thread 0x000000000bdd6800 Thread exited: 0x000000000bdd6800
Event: 809.068 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 809.070 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done

Dynamic libraries:...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the JDBC-ODBC Bridge (which is deprecated and has been removed from Java 8), you might have better luck using the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver. It is a pure Java implementation, so your process won't have to run code outside the JVM. For more details, see another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Comment: Fixed!

Replaced the setup with the UCanAccess driver and it works great!

Thanks Gord!